# How to use UIGestureRecognizer in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

So I want to have the tap gesture recognizer in my app where the user doesn't have to scroll the screen I want the gesture recognizer only be on the side of the app like 30 from the right and the left.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

[image: third image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var images = [UIImageView]()
    var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    var contentAdded = false

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if !contentAdded {
            contentAdded = true

            for x in 0...2 {
                let image = UIImage(named: "icon\(x).png")
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                images.append(imageView)

                var newX: CGFloat = 0.0
                newX = view.frame.midX + view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(x)

                contentWidth += view.frame.size.width

                scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: newX - 75, y: (view.frame.size.height / 2) - 75, width: 150, height: 150)

            }
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.size.height)

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to simulate prev / next with gesture

Comment: Whatever best for the user interface

Comment: Add 2 invisible views to the left & right respectively with the width say 30 and add the gesture to them , then add them to the main view not to the scrollView

Comment: What is your issue now?  No need to add invisible views. You can add the recognizer to the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One of the simple ways is to add invisible views on top of the z-order and attach tap gesture recogniser to the same. AutoLayout stuff to support dynamic orientation changes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Call this at the end to make sure our Left/Right taps are on top of z-index
    setupLeftRightTaps()
}

func setupLeftRightTaps() {
    let leftView = UIView()
    // leftView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    leftView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftTap)))
    view.addSubview(leftView)

    let rightView = UIView()
    // rightView.backgroundColor = .red
    rightView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightTap)))
    view.addSubview(rightView)

    // Layout
    rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        leftView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        leftView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        leftView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),

        rightView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        rightView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        rightView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        rightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
}

@objc func leftTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Left Tapped")
}

@objc func rightTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Right Tapped")
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you need UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer

```
/*! This subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer only recognizes if the user slides their finger
in from the bezel on the specified edge. */
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED @interface UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign) UIRectEdge edges; //< The edges on which this gesture recognizes, relative to the current interface orientation
@end
```